# Не могу разобраться с Yandex Cloud API

Tags: c#, api

Пытаюсь подключить Yandex Cloud Translation API в свой c# проект для домашнего задания, но не понимаю как это сделать. В документации есть примеры кода на Python, CLI. Также нашел в справочнике API две вкладки: REST и gRPC, но понятия не имею что это и как с этим работать. До этого 1 раз пользовался просто по ссылке апишкой сайта с погодой и проблем не было, а тут все как-то сложно. Подскажите как на c# отправлять такие запросы и как будет приходить ответ на запрос.

Comment: `В документации` - нам ее конечно не покажете, самим надо искать, изучать, да? `а тут все как-то сложно` - все API работают +- одинаково, у них есть адрес (ссылка), есть заголовки (в которых может быть ключ авторизации), есть тело запроса (в котором вы в конкретном формате передаете, например слово для перевода), ну а на запрос сервер дает вам ответ. Вот изучите документацию, поймите, что и куда отсылается, попробуйте это сделать через Postman например, а уж затем пробуйте писать C# код.

Answer (score 0):

Для работы с gRPC API Yandex Cloud есть Nuget пакет в котором реализован SDK. https://github.com/yandex-cloud/dotnet-sdk.

По сути это довольно тонкая прослойка над gRPC, которая упрощает авторизацию в API и берет на себя endpoint discovery.
В остальном вам стоит опираться на документацию, там обычно подробно расписаны параметры запросов.

Могу лишь еще посоветовать [курс на Практикуме про Облако](https://practicum.yandex.ru/ycloud/). Он позволит вам более подробно ознакомиться со всеми концепциями.